# Fermat's Last Theorem: A natural extension

Tags: number-theory

It is well known that there are no solutions to

$$a_1^n+a_2^n=b^n$$

for $a_1,a_2,b\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ and $n>2$.

Is it then true that there are no solutions to

$$a_1^n+a_2^n+\cdots+a_m^n=b^n$$

for $a_1,\ldots,a_m,b\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ and $n>m$?

Comment: See [Euler's sum of powers conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_sum_of_powers_conjecture) and the [Lander, Parkin, and Selfridge conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lander,_Parkin,_and_Selfridge_conjecture).

Comment: see book by Richard K. Guy, Unsolved Problems in Number Theory. Euler's conjecture was that one needed $m \geq n$ I think, anyway not true, one may do better sometimes

Comment: @Lucian, Oh wow. I wonder what the minimum value for $n$ is given $m$ such that no solutions exist. That could be a nice sequence for OEIS.

Comment: No, in 1986, there's a counter-example discovered by Noam Elikies: $2682440^4+15365639^4+18796760^4=20615673^4$.

Comment: It would be a nice sequence if it had some known values.

Comment: @user254665, at the right end of your comment, I can see a picture of a pencil. If you place the mouse arrow near that, you should also see an icon of an X; if you click on that, it will delete the comment, possibly after asking you for confirmation..  Alright, I just saved this comment, what I see is the word "edit" at the end along with a delete option. Apparently the pencil just means your comment was edited at least once after the initial save.